# New trilogy about a battle between ancient inhabited spires or towers

Tags: story-identification, books, novel, aliens

About a year ago (i.e. in 2020) I read a book which was intended to be the first of a trilogy about a sneaky invasion by the inhabitants of one giant spire against another. The story is told from the point of view of the inhabitants of the spire that is invaded, and tells how they discover and partially fight the well trained army of the other. Each of the floors had different characteristics and different wealths. One floor had a port for incoming air ships, another was a floor for the benevolent royal family. There were different creatures as well as humans, including clans of sentient cats. These cats had their own ways of doing things. The heroine’s cat helps organise a defence of the invasion of spiders that are working with the human attackers. Each spire had its own (air)navy with heavy battleships and lighter, more nimble cruisers.

The inhabitants of the spires had no memory of who and when the spires were built. The spires were built of a very resistant and long lasting material. The inhabitants would alter the interior by building with wood and stone but they could not change or destroy the original.

I could not read the next in the series because at that time it had not yet been written. I made a mental note to look for the next but, in the last year, I forgot the name of the book and of its author.

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/kindle/series/B08G1W1JQM?

Answer (score 24):

Could this be [*The Aeronaut's Windlass*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/24876258-the-aeronaut-s-windlass) by Jim Butcher?

> Since time immemorial, the Spires have sheltered humanity, towering
> for miles over the mist-shrouded surface of the world. Within their
> halls, aristocratic houses have ruled for generations, developing
> scientific marvels, fostering trade alliances, and building fleets of
> airships to keep the peace

[image]

Comment: And if so, you'll be sad to hear that the next book ("[The Olympian Affair](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/26860699-the-olympian-affair)") hasn't yet been released, despite being promised [since 2018](https://www.jim-butcher.com/faq/upcoming-works).

Comment: I concur that this is the first book in The Cinder Spires. The description perfectly fits the book, down to the sentient cats and and the invasion of spiders.

Comment: @Valorum - He had some issues with the development of the last entries in his big Dresden Files series that likely delayed things (what was supposed to be one novel eventually turned into 2, released a couple months of each other). The second Cinder Spires is listed above the next Dresden Files novel in his upcoming releases on his official website, if that means anything.